# How do I merge rows in the same dataframe in R

Tags: r, merge, tidyr

I have a large dataset that looks like this:

```
   data.frame(cbind(id=c(01,01,02,03,04,04),sex=c("---","m","f","m","---","f"),
             age=c(20,NA,25,23,NA,18),height=c(NA,180,175,168,176,NA),
             weight=c(68,NA,65,68,NA,NA)))

     id sex  age height weight
     01 ---   20   <NA>     68
     01   m <NA>    180   <NA>
     02   f   25    175     65
     03   m   23    168     68
     04 --- <NA>    176   <NA>
     04   f   18   <NA>   <NA>
```

How can I merge the rows to fill out the missing values like this:

```
     id sex  age height weight
     01  m   20   180     68
     02  f   25   175     65
     03  m   23   168     68
     04  f   18   176   <NA>
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: That's more of a group_by and summarize operation. What if there were a third row for id 04 with a non-missing age? What would the expected output be?

Comment: you tagged 'data.table' when I suspect you didn't mean the specific package but were thinking generically that you have a table full of data.  In any case, it's a good package that's been around for almost a decade.  https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  fill(everything()) %>% 
  filter(sex != "---") %>%
  ungroup()
```

The default direction of `fill` is "down" so this works given the order of your dataframe. Otherwise, you will have to arrange your dataframe first.

**Output**

```
  id    sex   age   height weight
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr> 
1 1     m     20    180    68    
2 2     f     25    175    65    
3 3     m     23    168    68    
4 4     f     18    176    NA
```

Answer (score 0):

We could group by 'id', `summarise` `across` other columns, convert the `---` to `NA`, while removing the `NA` elements with `na.omit` (we assume that all the columns have same number of NA element).  If all the elements are NA for a group, return `NA`

```
library(dplyr)    
df1 %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarise(across(everything(), 
      ~ if(all(is.na(.))) NA else na.omit(na_if(., '---'))), .groups = 'drop')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 x 5
#     id sex     age height weight
#* <dbl> <chr> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#1     1 m        20    180     68
#2     2 f        25    175     65
#3     3 m        23    168     68
#4     4 f        18    176     NA
```

---

We could also `order` individual columns based on the `NA` or `---` after grouping by 'id' and then use `filter` with `if_all` to remove those rows having only those missing elements

```
df1 %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ .[order(is.na(.)| . == '---')])) %>% 
  filter(!if_all(everything(),  ~ is.na(.)|. == '---')) %>% 
  ungroup
# A tibble: 4 x 5
#     id sex     age height weight  
#   <dbl> <chr> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#1     1 m        20    180     68
#2     2 f        25    175     65
#3     3 m        23    168     68
#4     4 f        18    176     NA
```

> 

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4), sex = c("---", "m", 
"f", "m", "---", "f"), age = c(20, NA, 25, 23, NA, 18), height = c(NA, 
180, 175, 168, 176, NA), weight = c(68, NA, 65, 68, NA, NA)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Answer (score 0):

The `data.table` solution would be something like this

assuming your `data.frame` is named `DT`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DT) #convert the dataframe to data.table
DT[,lapply(.SD, max,na.rm=TRUE),by='id']
```

the syntax for `data.table` is `DT[i, j, by]` where `i` is a filter, `j` is an action, and `by` is grouping.  What we're doing here is, firstly opening with a comma because we're not doing any filtering so our `i` in this case is blank.  Our `j` is `lapply(.SD,max,na.rm=TRUE)`.  The `lapply` is just a loop that returns a list, it's looping on `.SD` which is a `data.table` function which basically means all columns.  The second argument of `lapply` is the function we want to perform on all of the columns.  The third argument is an extra argument which is fed to `max` so that it'll ignore NAs.  The `by` argument is your 'id' which is what you want your rows to be unique by.

The caveat with this answer is that if you ever have multiple correct values then this takes the biggest of them so you'll need to substitute `max` with something more appropriate.